# API destination has become inactive on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I want to call an API after every 2 hours, have created an eventbridge rule. Used target as API destination. It worked for the first time, somehow failed.

Now the status of API destination is "inactive", how can we make it active?

Have not found any document related to status os API destination.

Comment: Please share the code block